# @DeclareRoles works only with some roles, not with others

Tags: java, rest, security, jakarta-ee, roles

I have a .war project which I deploy on a local Payara Application Server.
It contains a RESTful Service in which I check for caller authorization by adding the `@RolesAllowed` annotation.
In that same project I also have an empty class which only contains the annotation `@DeclareRoles`:

```
    @DeclareRoles({"administrator", "all_access"})
    public class DeclareRolesClass {
        //do nothing...
    }
```

The user is assigned groups by a separately implemented soteria based authentication mechanism. If I ask for the assigned groups, both "administrator" and "all_access" are returned so the groups seem to be assigned correctly.

However if I use `@RolesAllowed({"administrator"})` on one of the REST-methods the request is denied.
Checking for caller roles with `securityContext.isCallerInRole("administrator")` also returns `false`.

Oddly enough though the role "all_access" works just fine in every scenario.

I already tried putting the `@DeclareRoles` annotation above the class that contains the REST-method which was annotated with `@RolesAllowed`, but to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea as to where the error could be?
Did I misunderstand something fundamental about the `@DeclareRoles` annotation?

Additional Information:
I use the implicit mapping from caller_groups to caller_roles in which I don't specify any mapping in the glassfish-web.xml. Instead the mapping should just transfer all groups directly to roles of the same name.
(And it actually does do that for the "all_access" group)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround today. It doesn't really solve the issue but at least it works for now. Maybe this helps someone how stumbles upon the same problem.

The implicit mapping from user-groups to user-roles seems to be problematic. One group ("all_access") gets mapped but others don't.
(If anyone knows why this might happen I'd appreciate any ideas)

So adding an explicit mapping in the glassfish-web.xml for all roles that are going to be used did the trick for me.
Now all roles that are mapped in the glassfish-web.xml and declared by the `@DeclareRoles()` annotation function correctly.

```
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>all_access</role-name>
    <group-name>all_access</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>

<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    <group-name>administrator</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
```